# Using Laravel's toSql on queries using 'with' clause

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm working in Laravel and I'm interested in checking the SQL statements generated by a Eloquent query that includes a with() statement.  For some reason I'm getting only the main query.  For example, when I run

```
class Child extends EloquentVersioned {
    public function childRequests()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('ChildRequest');
    }   

}
$childQuery = Child::orderBy('last_name')->orderBy('first_name')->with( 'childRequests');
return $childQuery->toSql();
```

I get back:

```
select `children`.* from `children` order by `last_name` asc, `first_name` asc
```

How do I get back the SQL for the with('childRequests') query?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually, when using `with` then `Laravel` uses another query for that so you are not getting that query output but if you use `DB::getQueryLog()` then you'll get all the query logs and to get your log you may run the actual query, for example:

```
Child::orderBy('last_name')->orderBy('first_name')->with( 'childRequests')->get();
```

Now try this:

```
dd(DB::getQueryLog()); // an array of all queries
```

You'll get an output of your queries and you may find the last query using:

```
$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
dd(end($queries)); // only last query
```

Troubleshooting

> If you get no results on `DB::getQueryLog()` then the Query Logger may be disabled at all and you have to use `DB::enableQueryLog()` before.

Comment: Ok, that's handy.  Will the "last" query include all of the queries generated by the Child call, or do I somehow need to work my way backwards through dd?

Comment: `$queries = DB::getQueryLog()` Here the `$queries` will contain all the queries in an array and the last query will contain only the last one and in this case you won't get the thing you are looking for because when you use `with` behind the scene `Laravel` executes another query for the relation.

Comment: Is there any documentation of the dd() function I can check out?  If there are parameters for pulling end-1 I could navigate back enough steps to grab the queries I know should be getting executed.

Comment: Does $queries contain only the queries generated by the most recently executed Eloquent command, or all queries in the current session?  I was assuming the latter, but if it's just the most recent bundle I have what I need with your original answer.

Comment: `dd` is a helper function and available in `helpers.php` in `Illuminate/Support/..` and `$queries` will contain all queries.

Comment: Nice Some Time The Query Log Is Disabled You Need To Enabled `DB::enableQueryLog();`

Comment: @Zymawy thanks for the hint. If you get no results on `DB::getQueryLog()` then the Query Logger may be disabled at all and you have to use `DB::enableQueryLog()` before.