# Laravel with subquery ignores where

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have an application in which

An EventDateItem belongs to an Event, an Event has Categories, and an Event has CollectionItems

I have the following query

```
$eventsQuery = EventDateItem::with([
    'event.categories',
    'event.collectionItems' => function ($q) use ($collectionItem) {
        $q->select('thisdoesntexist');
    }
])->whereDate('date', '>', Carbon::now());
```

What happens when I return the sql using `toSql()`, is the following

```
select * from `event_date_items` where date(`date`) > ?
```

So it's ignoring my with() clause, and the where clause inside of it.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Laravel performs an additional query to load the relations so they will not show up with `toSql`, you will have to use `DB::getQueryLog()` to get all performed queries. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22489526/9193055).

Comment: Did you get the answer you're looking for ? or you need more information ?

Comment: Well I understand what they're saying but it doesn't really solve the issue here. There must be a way to select the columns from the relations you're including?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The With clause is used in a second **Query**, more info [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading)

In practice, it does a **first Query** on the main `Model` (`EventDateItem` in your example)

Then **another Query** per relation that looks like this `SELECT thisdoesntexist FROM collection_items where event_date_item_id in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`.

The place holders in the second Query are the ids returned from the first one.

Answer (score 0):

`with()` statements are not executed in the same sql query, these are executed after the main query has been resolved and then mapped on the correct models.

If you want to be able to see all queries, you can use a tool like [laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar).